# How do I derive the center of the symplectic group?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, lie-groups, symplectic-linear-algebra

I define the real symplectic group to be the set of $2n \times 2n$ matrices satisfying
\begin{equation}
S\Omega S^\intercal = \Omega,
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
\Omega = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}

The center of a group is the set of matrices that commute with every one of its elements. I have read that the center of the real symplectic group is $\{I_{2n},-I_{2n}\}$. How do I prove this?

Comment: You could show that it acts absolutely irreducibly on ${\mathbb R}^n$, and then deduce it from Schur's lemma. For the absolute irreducibility, first do it for $n=1$ when ${\rm Sp}(2,{\mathbb R}) = {\rm SL}(2,{\mathbb R})$, and then use the fact that the sympectic group is generated ny $n$ copies of ${\rm Sp}(2,{\mathbb R})$ and a permutation matrix.